# How to call child component's function from parent without use of @viewChild in angular?

Tags: angular, parent, emit

I have one problem. I am trying to repeat the component dynamically through `ngFor` and My main component want it's all repeated child's data through button click.

Look at below for more understanding :

[image]

I want to get all child component's internal data into parent component on the button click of the parent component. But I don't know how to listen click event of parent's button into child component.

Can you please help me to fulfil this kind of scenario. I will very thankful if anyone help me.

**Note :** I can't take any reference through viewchild of child component to call child method from parent because child components are render dynamically through `*ngFor`

Comment: `child component's internal data` what does it mean ? You want to pass click event to child component or vice versa? Does the child components rendered by the time you click on the buttons? Add some more context and code.

Comment: YEs, I want to get all child component's data into parent component when click on parent;'s button click.

Child components are added dynamically by another button that is not mention in image.

Comment: I already use it to emit data from child component. but problem is when click on parent's button, I want to emit data. how can i detect parent's click event into child ?

Comment: What kind of (child) data are we talking about here? A service might make sense..?

Comment: child component will process one kind of json like data: { key: value, key: value }
each child will emit one json object

Comment: And all child's json will goes into parent and then parent wil process that json  further

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you mean by `child component's internal data`. Assuming that you want to call the methods and access properties. You can use @ViewChild

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({ 
  selector: 'child-cmp', 
  template: `<h2> Child Component</h2> ` 
})
export class ChildComponent {

  TestCmp() { 
   console.log("Child component!"); 
  }
 }
```

In parent component you can do this:

```
  import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { ChildComponent } from '../child/child'; 
    @Component({ 
               selector: 'parent-app', 
               template: `<child-cmp></child-cmp>` 
              }) 
    export class parentComponent implements OnInit{ 
        @ViewChild(ChildComponent, {static: false }) child: ChildComponent ; 

// it will be available after ngAfterViewInit

        ngAfterViewInit() { 
           this.child.ChildTestCmp(); } 
}
```

The above method can help you call different methods and access properties.

Now, if you want to pass event to the child component, you can use `RXJS Subject`. Whenever an event occurs in the parent component you can get the value in the child component.

For that you should create a service and initialise it.
test.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService { 
   constructor () {}
   const subject = new Subject<number>();
}
```

Import the service in the Child and Parent Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from 'test.service'
    import { ChildComponent } from '../child/child'; 
    @Component({ 
               selector: 'parent-app', 
               template: `<child-cmp></child-cmp>` 
              }) 
    export class parentComponent implements OnInit{ 
        @ViewChild(ChildComponent, {static: false }) child: ChildComponent ; 

       constructor(private testService: TestService) {}
// it will be available after ngAfterViewInit

        ngAfterViewInit() { 
           this.child.ChildTestCmp(); } 
    
         someEventHappen() {
           this.testService.subject(true);
         }

}
```

In child component, you can get the event:

```
import { Component , OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from 'test.service'
@Component({ 
  selector: 'child-cmp', 
  template: `<h2> Child Component</h2> ` 
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnDestroy{
  subs: subscription[] = [];
 constructor(private testService: TestService) {
    // unsubscribe all the subs
     const subs = this.testService.subject().subscribe(data => {
      // do something
      });
    this.subs.push(subs);

}

  TestCmp() { 
   console.log("Child component!"); 
  }

   ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subs.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
   }
 }
```

You can also use the same service to keep data for all the children though I would suggest you to create a state management for them and it will help you to maintain it nicely.